# Kernel dies while trying to save a mathplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Before my question, that's the setup:

MacBook Air (M2, 2022)

macOS Monterey 12.5.1

Visual Studio Code 1.72.2

Python 3.8.9

I am trying to create multiple figures in a for-loop using mathplotlib. I've uploaded some testable code for the project here:
https://onecompiler.com/python/3ykd8g2hs

The creation works and notebooks shows me the figures. But when I try to save the figures, the process breaks and the following error message follows:

```
The kernel 'Python 3.8.9 64-bit' died and is being automatically restarted by Jupyter. Click [here](https://aka.ms/vscodeJupyterKernelCrash) for more info. View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
```

Log:

```
[I 21:27:32.698 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
[I 21:27:32.706 NotebookApp] Starting buffering for 2d60d5cc-c336-45fa-8e0c-a2357d2e626a:23ed7ab8-14f2-4b21-ab52-a0af269f221d
[I 21:27:32.724 NotebookApp] Restoring connection for 2d60d5cc-c336-45fa-8e0c-a2357d2e626a:23ed7ab8-14f2-4b21-ab52-a0af269f221d
```

I have already tried several things:
Uninstall and reinstall various libraries,
create a new virtual environment
Reinstall Python

Nothing has helped so far.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: You could have a look at this [subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/m07q1z/kernel_dying_in_jupyter_notebook_with_matplotlib/). It may has some of the answers you are looking for to save your problem.

Comment: To help us understand the problem, make the code run as a complete minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You should show your code and tell us what you did to get this error.

Comment: Sorry, I've added some Code here: https://onecompiler.com/python/3ykd8g2hs

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code for me. How are you running your code? and do you have any other settings in vscode? Still, I recommend that you provide the full error log, or file your special issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/new/choose).

Answer (score 0):

Try to install a lower version of `pyzmq` with the following command

```
python -m pip install pyzmq==19.0.2 --force-reinstall
```

Comment: Thank you, I've already tried that - but the error still exists...